# How to center an element with some fixed margin?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set an element's margin to it's automatic value (I want to keep it centered) plus a specific amount of pixels, but `calc(auto + 20px)` doesn't seem to be working. Here's my code:

```
#game {
    border: 5px groove orange;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: calc(auto + 20px);
    margin-right: calc(auto + 20px);
    display: block;
}
```

Are there any alternatives to this approach?

Comment: Which is the purpose of that ? "+20px" at each side will keep the element at the same exact position as `auto`

Comment: Why dont you use padding-left and padding-right with 20px each and leave margin auto? Is there a problem with that? Maybe a small html along with this would help.

Comment: @Hassan If I use padding the page would display blank space between the content of the element and its border and I don't want that to happen

Comment: Ok I see there is a border too. So a padding would give you space between border and content. Then what DaniP said, what are you trying to achieve? Maybe we can help if you give a more elaborate sample.

Comment: @Hassan The element I'm trying to modify is inside a div, and I want the div to be large a little larger than the element. I'm trying to accomplish that by setting the div's width to auto and the elements margin to auto (to keep centered) plus a fixed amount. Do you know if I can do this in a different way?

Comment: @DaniP I answered your comment above

Comment: [This seems to be an XY problem then.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42675350/setting-elements-margin-to-its-auto-value-plus-a-fixed-amount/42675520#comment72475629_42675350) Why can't you use padding on the parent element then?

Comment: Voting to close because the question is unclear or it lacks relevant and complete information regarding the use-case. It simply lacks an MCVE.

Comment: *a little larger than the element* ... Like this https://jsfiddle.net/odq2j0zn/ ?

Comment: @DaniP No, I want the outer div to be a little larger than the inner div

Comment: Then why not just margin on element https://jsfiddle.net/odq2j0zn/1/ .... or padding on parent https://jsfiddle.net/odq2j0zn/2/

Comment: @DaniP Thank you for your help, I've already fixed the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with adding an additional container.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  |<div class="inner">Hello world</div>|
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I tried your solution and it worked

Answer (score 1):

So in our understanding you have an outer div (lets id it game-container) and an inner div (with id game). The inner div is centered and you want the outer div to be a little bigger than the inner one which means right now its sticking to its border. As Abhitalks suggested correctly, you can easily add padding to outer element and achieve this.

```css
#game {
    border: 5px groove orange;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue; /*for demo*/
}

#game-container{
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green; /*for demo*/
}
```

```html
  <div id='game-container'>
    <div id='game'>
      <h1>Sprite</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If there are other elements in your outer div, you can add another new div around game and apply its CSS as game-container.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :)